# Determining protocol with url_for and link_to on symfony

Tags: php, object, symfony1, hyperlink, symfony-1.4

I want to change the default protocol used with link_to and url_for function from symfony. I dind't find any good way on the documentation. My solution is to generate absolute url and subsitute the http: by an https:, i don't find it clean and nice.

So do you have an answer?

Thanks.

Comment: Hm, as far as I know, and it's stated in the docs, you can specify protocol of your uri for absolute paths: `echo link_to('Visit Hoogle', 'http://www.hoogle.com'); `

Comment: OK but what can i do with something like this : 

`link_to('info', '@info');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set sfRouting parameters to generate https urls or urls with a different protocol. Check out the `sfRouting::fixGeneratedUrl` method.

However, if you're only interested in this for generating https links, I strongly recommend using a filter approach. The [sfSslRequirementPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfSslRequirementPlugin) was written for 1.1, but will work with some modifications. Alternatively, there's [this solution](http://blog.tigregroup.com/programming/creating-an-ssl-redirect-filter-in-symfony/) written for 1.3/1.4, but I have never used it.

A filter approach is required to ensure that your secure actions are only being accessed securely and will let you be unconcerned with how URLs are generated.

Comment: Great, thank you! It's a shame that url_for or link_tot doesn't implement an option protocol.